# How to calculate an SQL MAX() for any N-second duration within a certain timeframe

Tags: sql

I need to answer a question like this:

> For each **user**, what is the **most items** that user viewed in any 60 second
>   time frame between `START_TIMESTAMP` and `END_TIMESTAMP`?

***The 60 second time frame is a sliding window***. It's not just a matter of "items viewed" counts for each whole minute. Also, 60 seconds was just an example, it should work for any number of seconds.

My data is stored like this:

```
-- Timestamped log of users viewing items
CREATE TABLE user_item_views (
  user_id integer,
  item_id integer,
  timestamp timestamp
);
```

Doing it for each whole minute is easy enough, just format timestamp to something like `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm` and do a count grouped by that formatted timestamp and the user_id.

Doing it for a sliding window, I have no idea how to approach.

If this would be easier outside of SQL, I am open to exporting the data to another format, or using another language.

Desired output is something like:

```
User ID  Max items viewed in N seconds, between START and END.
...      ...
...      ...
...      ...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what dbms is this? MSSQL Oracle MySQL?

Comment: @JoshBerke I can use anything open-source and preferably easily accessible. It needn't be an RDBMS if another tool is better suited. For RDBMS, in order of most-preferred to least-preferred: sqlite3, PostgreSQL or MySQL.

Comment: @Rebe I'd really appreciate some kind of feed-back whether my idea worked. Also, I'd love to see the code you ended up using!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it (beware, untested code, this ist just to outline the idea).

You need a helper table with as many rows as there are seconds between `START_TIMESTAMP` and `END_TIMESTAMP`. Create that as a temp table before you begin your query.

For the sake of the sample, let's call it `every_second`. I'm assuming your minimum time resolution is one second.

Then do:

```
SELECT
  s.timestamp,
  v.user_id,
  (
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_item_views 
    WHERE timestamp BETWEEN s.timestamp AND ADDTIME(s.timestamp, '00:00:59')
          AND user_id = v.user_id
  ) item_count
FROM
  every_second s
  LEFT JOIN user_item_views v ON v.timestamp = s.timestamp
GROUP BY
  s.timestamp, 
  v.user_id
```

Store that in another temporary table and select the desired maxima from it (this is necessary because of the "select max from group" problem).

Comment: @Rebe: I give no guarantees. Tell me how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL (assuming that `timestamp` is unique):

```
SELECT 
      user_id 
    , MAX(max_count) AS max_count
FROM
  ( SELECT 
          a.user_id 
        , COUNT(*)      AS max_count
    FROM 
          user_item_views AS a
      JOIN
          user_item_views AS b
        ON  a.user_id = b.user_id
        AND a.timestamp <= b.timestamp
        AND b.timestamp < a.timestamp + INTERVAL 60 SECOND
    GROUP BY 
          a.user_id
        , a.timestamp 
  ) AS grp
GROUP BY
      user_id
```